# how to get standard deviation of an aggregate of all values of a dataframe (or matrix), grouped by one variable

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, standard-deviation

I have a data frame with 13 columns. the 13th column shows the group number each row belongs to.  I want to take the standard deviation of all values in all rows of columns 3 to 12, for rows of each group.

```
 for(i in 1: groupnumber) {  
sd.vect[i] <- sd(as.vector(df[df$group==i,][,-c(1,2,13)]))}
```

I get error

> Error in is.data.frame(x) :
> 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

how can I get sd of all values in each group?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dplyr. You can `group_by(grouping_column)`, then `summarise()` with the `sd()` function:

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame%>%>group_by(thirteenth_column)%>%summarise(across(-c(1,2), sd))
```

As an example with mtcars:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars%>%group_by(cyl)%>%summarise(across(everything(), sd))

# A tibble: 3 x 11
    cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  4.51  26.9  20.9 0.365 0.570  1.68 0.302 0.467 0.539 0.522
2     6  1.45  41.6  24.3 0.476 0.356  1.71 0.535 0.535 0.690 1.81 
3     8  2.56  67.8  51.0 0.372 0.759  1.20 0     0.363 0.726 1.56
```

That said, with some corrections, your for loop works:
You just have to make sure to return a dataframe, as your desired outcome is actually a two-dimension object. See an example with the iris dataset:

```
sd.df<-data.frame()
for(i in unique(iris$Species)) {
        for (j in 1:ncol(iris[-5])){
        sd.df[i,j] <- sd(iris[iris$Species==i,j])
        }
}
sd.df

                  V1        V2        V3        V4
setosa     0.3524897 0.3790644 0.1736640 0.1053856
versicolor 0.5161711 0.3137983 0.4699110 0.1977527
virginica  0.6358796 0.3224966 0.5518947 0.2746501
```

**update**
I understand from your comments you may want something quite odd, which would be to group your data by the grouping variable, than get the standard deviation for an aggregate of all values in each sub-dataframe. You probably would be better off working with matrices here.
For that, you may neet to group your data by `unique()` values in the grouping column, then call `sd()` on the rest of the dataframe (all values), which can be done if you coerce the dataframe into a matrix:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map_dbl(unique(mtcars$cyl), ~as.matrix(mtcars%>%
                                           filter(cyl==.x)%>%
                                           select(-cyl))%>%
            sd())%>%
        set_names(., unique(mtcars$cyl))

        6         4         8 
 62.47655  37.54494 118.18945
```

With your data:

```
map(unique(df[[13]]), ~as.matrix(df%>%
                                   filter(df[[13]]==.x)%>%
                                   select(-c(1,2,13)))%>%
        sd()%>%
        set_names(., unique(df[[13]]))
```

And a much simpler answer with base subsetting and `split()`:

```
map_dbl(split(mtcars[-c(1,2, 10)], mtcars[10]), ~sd(as.matrix(.x)))

        3         4         5 
119.47824  47.97490  98.71733
```

Comment: thank you. I m just wondering shouldnt it be returning just one number as the result of sd? let say I have 20 rows whose 13th column is group3. so I need the sd of all 20*10 values. ( 10 = all 13 columns - 1st,2nd,13th)

Comment: But if you want it for every group, you would have an sd for every combination of group and column, and the number of rows wouldnt matter. If there are 13 columns and the 13th is the grouping column, for 3 groups, you would have 12*3=36 values returned

Comment: just to make sure, I m on the right path : here in mtcars example, all rows with cyl 6 are aggregated in one single row. now 1.45 in mpg column is the sd of all values in mpg column who had cyl6 in their cyl column?

Comment: Yes you are right, thats exactly that. I added an example with your for loop too

Comment: if you do not want a result for every group, but rather just remove the grouping column from the operation, you can just call `df%>%summarise(across(-grouping_column), sd)`

Comment: See my updated answer to see if i finally understand you, @Mathica

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! :) awsome explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the columns from `cur_data()` -

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(sd_value = sd(unlist(select(cur_data(), -(1:2)))))
```

Example using `mtcars` -

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarise(sd_value = sd(unlist(select(cur_data(), -(1:2)))))

#   gear sd_value
#  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     3    119. 
#2     4     48.0
#3     5     98.7
```

Comment: so easy with `unlist()`, i missed it

Answer (score 0):

Using `mtcars` as an example,

```r
aggregate(.~cyl, data=mtcars, FUN=sd)
#   cyl      mpg     disp       hp      drat        wt     qsec        vs        am      gear     carb
# 1   4 4.509828 26.87159 20.93453 0.3654711 0.5695637 1.682445 0.3015113 0.4670994 0.5393599 0.522233
# 2   6 1.453567 41.56246 24.26049 0.4760552 0.3563455 1.706866 0.5345225 0.5345225 0.6900656 1.812654
# 3   8 2.560048 67.77132 50.97689 0.3723618 0.7594047 1.196014 0.0000000 0.3631365 0.7262730 1.556624
```